# How to show child category name & post from it's parent

Tags: categories

I am new in wordpress. I want to show child post from its parent.like

.parent category 1

- child1 of parent 1 and 3 post from it (not other child post)
- child2 of parent 1 and 3 post from it (not other child post)
- child3 of parent 1 and 3 post from it (not other child post)

how can i do that?

Comment: Why are you inserting some CSS rules next to HTML? That doesn‘t work.

Comment: please give me a solution

Answer (score 2):

Assuming this is in a post or page editor using the "text" tab, you need to wrap the CSS in  tags.  So:

```
<style>
.section-list-item:nth-child(3n) {
padding: 1.87em 0em 1.25em 0em;
}
</style> 

<p> this is working in WordPress, I have solved it</p>
```